# How to define an interface with a method that either takes a IEnumerable<User> or just User

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have an interface for a message:

```
public interface IMessage
    {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Body { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    Employee CreatedBy { get; set; }
    MessageType MessageType { get; set; }

    void Send(IEnumerable<User> recipients);
    // or: void Send(User recipient);
    }
```

Every implementation must have a Send method that sends the message, but depending on the scenario the Send method is different. I.e. if it is a private message, there is only one recipient and it is also sent an additional mail notification to that spesific user, public messages does not do that.

The parameter can be either a list of users or a single user. How can I implement that?

I know I can just make a list of 1 user for the private message, but the best is if it is like an overloaded method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also mark it with params

```
Send(IEnumerable<User> users)
{...}

void Send(params User[] recipients)
{
    Send((IEnumerable<User>)recipients); // To IEnumerable overload
}
```

in which case you can pass in one, many or an array of Users.

Comment: Hi, I can't see this is any better really than IEnumerable<User>, only that it could be passed ass 100 parameters in some implementations, which is not really intuitive way of doing it... Or am i wrong?

Comment: This allows you to be more expressive without adding overloads, for example you could use it with multiple parameters or pack them into an array for consumption. Also see overload above to allow different clients to call the method transparently and only once piece of logic to handle it all.

Comment: That is actually much smarter than i first realized. I can now implement this method using Send(User to, User cc) or Send(User recipient), gives a lot more flexibility which i like in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Just overload the method - this is valid in an interface as well:

```
void Send(IEnumerable<User> recipients);
void Send(User recipient);
```

You would need to implement both overloads in the implementers of the interface.

Comment: When actually implementing it you can simply have the second overload just put the recipient into a collection and pass it to the other; it's not like the logic would need to be in both places.  You could also have an abstract class that does that so that base classes only need to define the enumerable overload.

Comment: OK, I can see that will work, but then I need to implement both possibilities, and I want to restrict the possibilities for each implementation.

Comment: @Servy - If you read the question carefully, the OP needs different behaviour.

Comment: @Servy How would you implement the abstract class?

Comment: @cfs - What abstract class? @Servy simply means that you can call `Send(IEnumerable<User> recipients)` from `Send(User recipient)` by wrapping the single `User` in a list.

Comment: @Oded yeah, I suppose it would depend on the specifics of how different it is.  It might be best to keep them separate, and it might be possible to combine them.

Comment: @cfs *"I want to restrict the possibilities for each implementation."* - you can have implementing classes throw a [NotImplementedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx) in the inappropriate method.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I guess I'll end up with the "overloaded" solution, and use the NotImplementedException or NotSupportedException for the implementation I want to restrict. I will do the job!